# Drywall skim coat over painted CMU?

Tags: drywall, concrete, painting

I have a small section of wall (50sf) where the stairwell goes into the basement that is CMU ([concrete masonry unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_masonry_unit) or concrete block) painted with at least an egg shell, possibly even semi-gloss.

Where the CMU from the basement level meets the textured drywall at the main level, the drywall overhangs the CMU by 1/8" to 1/4".

I was thinking of skim coating the CMU then matching texture and paint so it appears like drywall all the way to the basement floor.

Is there a product that can go over the painted surface to make it ready for a drywall skim so it sticks?  I figure sanding alone will not be enough due to the "rough" or "bumpy" surface of the CMU, the sandpaper won't make contact with the low areas.

Comment: Please try not to take offense at a comment suggesting an improvement to your post. See the [help center](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) for more information.

Comment: I take offense to my time being wasted.  No offense.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine all on its own, but if you want to be really really totally sure, just sand a bit to expose some of the CMU surface in the high areas.